# Not rendering application/x-openoffice-gdimetafile image data in browser

Tags: image, browser, libreoffice, sourceforge

In my code I parse `odt` file and store data as Html to render that on web page.
I am using `writer2latex15` with `embed_img` as true to have image inside data.

```
$SCRIPTDIR/writer2latex15/w2l -config
$SCRIPTDIR/writer2latex15/config/default.xml  -xhtml+mathml $F $HTMLDIR/$F
```

Now in some `odt` file unknown image format are getting converted in `application/x-openoffice-gdimetafile` format which is not getting rendered in browser.

Image tag is generated is as below.

```
<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" alt="graphics2" class="frameGraphics" id="graphics2graphic" src="data:application/x-openoffice-gdimetafile;windows_formatname=%22GDIMetaFile%22;base64,VkNMTVRGAQAxAAAAAQAAAAEAGwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAA....>
```

Full tag at: http://pastebin.com/FFFTDmsN

Please let me know if you know any config flag that will help me convert all images to png or jpeg or any setting that will show these images on chrome and firefox.

Comment: Will you provide the complete image tag?

Comment: nothing wrong with image tag.. looks like application/x-openoffice-gdimetafile is not supported.. I tried non embed option and tried to view image in browser but browser doent show that image.